# What is the difference between `(mcons (mcons '() 25) 16)` and `(mcons 25 (mcons 16 `()))`

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp, cons, cdr

I am busy with [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs exercise 2.18](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2). Here we have to define a procedure reverse to reverse a list. It should do the following:

```
(reverse (list 1 4 9 16 25))
;; => (25 16 9 4 1)
```

I came up with the following definition:

```
(define (reverse list)
  (if (null? list) 
      list
      (cons (reverse (cdr list)) (car list))))
;; => (mcons (mcons (mcons (mcons (mcons '() 25) 16) 9) 4) 1).
```

Then in [a solution](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-2.18) In found something similar as follows:

```
(define (reverse items) 
  (if (null? (cdr items)) 
      items 
      (append (reverse (cdr items)) 
              (cons (car items) nil))))
;; => (mcons 25 (mcons 16 (mcons 9 (mcons 4 (mcons 1 '()))))).
```

There's a difference between `append` and `cons` here where I cannot put my finger on.

My question: what is the difference and why are the results not displayed as `(25 16 9 4 1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the first version of `reverse` is incorrectly building an *improper* list, the second version is inefficiently building a *proper* list. We can do better as long as we understand the difference between `append` and `cons`.

`append` concatenates two *lists*. If we use it for just adding an element at the end of one list, we'll be doing a lot more of work than needed: we'll have to traverse the whole list *each time* just to put one last element (see: [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)). Hence a `reverse` implementation that uses `append` can be as bad as `O(n^2)` in complexity.

On the other hand, `cons` adds a single element to the head of a list, for an `O(n)` complexity in the implementation of `reverse`. In general, in Scheme you should try to avoid using `append` to build a new output list, always prefer `cons`. Now let's see what's being returned by your algorithm using `cons`:

```
(reverse '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(((((() . 5) . 4) . 3) . 2) . 1)
```

Why is that? because to build a proper list with `cons` the second argument must be another proper list, but you're passing a single element. A correct implementation requires an accumulator parameter - and incidentally, this is more efficient, because it uses *tail recursion*, a concept that you should already be familiar with, as it was introduced in section 1.2 of the book. Try this:

```
(define (reverse lst acc)
  (if (null? lst)
      acc
      (reverse (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))

(reverse '(1 2 3 4 5) '())
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

For the last part of the question: the list is being displayed with `mcons` (the `m` means that the `cons` cells are *mutable*) because of the language you're using, try switching to `#lang racket`, which uses *immutable* `cons` cells by default, and will get printed as you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using `#lang planet neil/sicp`, but will switch back to `#lang racket`.

Comment: @user2609980 don't switch so quickly though, `neil/sicp` is fine for working through the SICP exercises, whereas Racket will have some quirks. It'd be better if you just get used to lists being printed with all the `mcons` showing.